# excel vba loop through range and if statements

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I need help looping through a given range followed by an if statement.
My Range is:

```
| A    | B     | C    |
-----------------------
|TPA   | C:\   | 1.doc|

|TPA   | C:\   | 2.doc|

|LAX   | D:\   | 3.doc|
```

I want to loop through A1:C3 and if Column A1:A3 = "TPA" Then take the data of B1 and C1.

```
Dim test1 As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
cell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range ("A1:C3")
cell1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range ("A1:A3")
For Each cell1 in cell
If test1 = "TPA" Then 
'MsgBox B1 and C1 But I need to MsgBox B2 and C2 as well
End If
Next
```

Ultimately, I need to msgbox B1 + C1, and B2 + C2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim test1 As String, c As Range, myRng As Range
Dim Result as string

set myRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3")
For Each c in myRng
    If test1 = "TPA" Then 
        Result = Result & c & c.offset(0,1) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next c
MsgBox Result
```